# Aspose converting webpage to pdf

Tags: c#, aspose

I am using Aspose in a project to convert a webpage into a PDF document, majority of the document seems to be displaying fine Aspose seems to have an issue with certain bits of text or controls that go over multiple lines. I have done a search on the internet to see if i could find a solution, one suggested upgrading to version 18, so i have downloaded the latest version 19 but still to no avail. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

My code is

```
    <h4>The figures below should include your spouse or civil partner, where applicable.</h4><p>Please indicate your annual net disposable income (after all regular financial contributions):</p><div class="form-group radio-group " ><label class="col-sm-0 control-label  "></label><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="">
            <label>
                <input 
                        type="radio" 
                        name="AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome" 
                        value="Above £100,000" 
                        onclick="broadcastChange('AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome')"


                        />
                Above £100,000
            </label>
        </div><div class="">
            <label>
                <input 
                        type="radio" 
                        name="AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome" 
                        value="£50,000 - £100,000" 
                        onclick="broadcastChange('AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome')"


                        />
                £50,000 - £100,000
            </label>
        </div><div class="">
            <label>
                <input 
                        type="radio" 
                        name="AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome" 
                        value="£25,000 - £50,000" 
                        onclick="broadcastChange('AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome')"


                        />
                £25,000 - £50,000
            </label>
        </div><div class="">
            <label>
                <input 
                        type="radio" 
                        name="AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome" 
                        value="£10,000 - £25,000" 
                        onclick="broadcastChange('AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome')"


                        />
                £10,000 - £25,000
            </label>
        </div><div class="">
            <label>
                <input 
                        type="radio" 
                        name="AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome" 
                        value="£5,000 - £10,000" 
                        onclick="broadcastChange('AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome')"


                        />
                £5,000 - £10,000
            </label>
        </div><div class="">
            <label>
                <input 
                        type="radio" 
                        name="AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome" 
                        value="Less than £5,000" 
                        onclick="broadcastChange('AQAnnualNetDisposalIncome')"


                        />
                Less than £5,000
            </label>
        </div><span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span><div class="help-block with-errors">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Please indicate the value of your assets (excluding your residence), net of any loans or other liabilities:</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified what was causing the issue it was caused by a `min-height:30px` to get around the issue i overridden this property by setting `min-height: initial !important;`